# What is the best way to find SURF-features only on changed areas of frame?

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, opencv3.0, surf, opencv-features2d

For example, I calculate SURF descriptors for frames from real-time 50 fps FullHD video by using GPU: [`gpu::SURF_GPU`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#gpu::SURF_GPU) But it is slow, and I can't calculate it for each frame, only for 10 fps.

Video camera is stationary and fixed, so I can use the following optimization - calculate the descriptors only on the changed areas of the frame.
I use [`gpu::MOG2_GPU`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/video.html#gpu::MOG2_GPU) background subtractor, get foreground mask, and recalculate SURF descriptors only for crossing `mask & frame`. This is much more faster.

```
gpu::GpuMat frame, mask;

gpu::MOG2_GPU mog2GPU;
mog2GPU(frame, mask);

// do I need to do this?
/*
    gpu::GpuMat frame_src = frame.clone();
    int const dilation_size = 30;
    Mat element_dilate = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, // MORPH_RECT, MORPH_CROSS, 
        Size(2 * dilation_size + 1, 2 * dilation_size + 1),
        Point(dilation_size, dilation_size))
    gpu::dilate(frame_src, frame, element_dilate);
*/

gpu::SURF_GPU surfGPU;
surfGPU(frame, mask, keypoints, descriptors);
```

Is that enough, or it is necessary to increase the zone of masking using [`gpu::dilate()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/image_filtering.html#void%20gpu::dilate(const%20GpuMat&%20src,%20GpuMat&%20dst,%20const%20Mat&%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20int%20iterations))?

And if I need to do this, then how many pixels are used to calculate each SURF descriptor - i.e. what value do I need to pass to the function [`gpu::dilate()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/image_filtering.html#void%20gpu::dilate(const%20GpuMat&%20src,%20GpuMat&%20dst,%20const%20Mat&%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20int%20iterations)) as `kernel` and `dilation_size`?

Comment: just a guess but I think a mask should only be applied for keypoint detection, not for descriptor computation. dilate (or better close operators) then should only be necessary if your foreground mask isnt good enough.

Comment: @Micka Thank you! But "close operators" - what do you mean?

Comment: dilates followed by same number of erodes. this will close small holes in your mask, hopefully those who came from noise

Comment: @Micka  Yes, I tried it. But the irony is that `gpu::erode` - works as slowly as `gpu::SURF_GPU`.

Comment: erode should have the same speed as dilate. In the end it isn't important to perform the erode. Whether you need dilates at all depends on your mask quality. Post some sample images of your masks with/without dilates, otherwise impossible to tell whether it's necessary.